# How to open link in new tab from left side of current tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on an HTML project, and I can't find out how to open the new link from **left side of the current tab**, its by default open from right side, so I want to open in a new tab from **left side**. Any ideas please ??

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: try to use target="_blank" in your attribute

Comment: Why you want it to open in left side only?

Comment: @UdhayTitus but its open from right side of current tab and i want to open it from left side

Comment: Are you trying to make something like adware ?

Comment: Like in some ad sites when you click a link it opens a new page from the left

Comment: Why need it to open to the left side? Does the default not satisfy you?

Comment: You cannot do this in easy way but there is another way or logic. The page that you wants to open as a new tab open it in the current page and open your current page in a new tab. This is how the most of the ad sites do.

Comment: @VivekSingh yes i use it for advertising purpose, thanks for your logic i think its better solution to till now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#link').click(function(){
           var win = window.open('demo.html', '_blank');
           win.focus(); // opens current page in new tab
       }); 
    });
    </script>
    <body>
        <a id="link" href="new.html" target="_top">Ads link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, would have never thought to do it that way :) its work for me :D Thanks @Vivek Singh