# How to make the href link to open in the new right hand-side direction tab in React.js

Tags: reactjs, href, onclicklistener, location-href

The href is not opening in the new tab/windows at the right hand-side tab, however is opening at the left hand-side tab

import resume from "../files/resume.pdf"

```
        {/* Links to the Contact me  */}
         <a href="#contactme" onClick={handleClick("contactme")}> 
           Contact Me 
         </a>

         <a href={resume} onClick={()=> window.open("_blank", "resume")}> 
           Resume 
         </a> 
       </HStack>
```

Expecting the resume to be opened to the new tab at the right direction, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133542/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-from-left-side-of-current-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code snippet

```
<a href='../files/resume.pdf' target='_blank'> 
   Resume 
</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href={resume} onClick={()=> window.open("_blank", "resume")}> 
   Resume 
</a>
```